# Подготовленные выражения в MySQLI

Tags: mysqli

Как передать массив в подготовленные выражения?

```
$vht = new mysqli(…);
$sql = $vht->prepare("INSERT INTO `gg` VALUES (?, ?)"); 
$sql->bind_param('si', $name, $date); **<<<< сюда**
$name = 'Имя';
$date = 18;
$sql->execute(); 
$sql->close();
```

Comment: Это невозможно. только в цикле по массиву вызывать execute

Comment: Mike, а в PDO?!

Comment: Это ни какое средство доступа к базе не обеспечит. mysql видит 2 вопросительные знака - значит переменных 2.

Answer (score 1):

В mysqli необходимо использовать call_user_func_array();

В PDO и можно, и рекомендуется передавать сразу массив:

```
$name = 'Имя';
$date = 18;
$massiv = [$name, $date];

$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `gg` VALUES (?, ?)")->execute($massiv);
```

Есл же массив содержит данные для нескольких вставок - то этот массив следует перебирать в цикле и выполнять подготовленное выражение внутри этого цикла.

Comment: Ипатьев, не совсем понял ваш пример, вот mysqli там мы выставляем ещё типы s/i/... в pdo разве не нужно такого делать?

Comment: Можно, но не нужно. Любые переменные можно передавать в Mysql с типом string - что PDO и делает.